# Error con el initComponents al crear nuevos objetos

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

de ante mano Gracias por entrar.
me encontré con la peculiaridad de que cuando quise agregar un nuevo objeto en mi interfaz a utilizando la paleta, al momento de ejecutar el código me tira el siguiente error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: vistas_agentes/CargaSiniestro
    at vistas_principales.PanelAgente.btnCargarDatosActionPerformed(PanelAgente.java:592)
    at vistas_principales.PanelAgente.access$1200(PanelAgente.java:31)
    at vistas_principales.PanelAgente$14.actionPerformed(PanelAgente.java:454)
```

Resulta que estoy manejando en una sola interfaz muchos objetos y al editar las propiedades de todos los objetos el initComponents ya llego a mas de 5.300 lineas de codigo autogenerado.

¿esto tiene un limite de linea de codigo? porque el programa anda de lo mas bien, pero si copio y pego por ejemplo un jButton ya con sus propiedades o si arrastro un nuevo jButton a la interfaz y le modifico las propiedades, me salé el error de mas arriba... como si el initComponents tuviera algun tope de lineas la cual al pasarse empieza a tirar el:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

[image: Imagen de ejemplo]

Como se ve en la imagen es un jButton común con algunas propiedades modificadas...

*el codigo automatico que se crea en el initComponents:

[image: Imagen para demostrar que están creadas una igual a la otra]

no hay nada raro... se crea igual que al jbutton anterior, pero no es cosa del jbutton, si pongo varios objetos nuevos arrastrados desde la paleta sin modificarle las propiedades, también me salta el error ya mencionado, por eso me hace dudar que el initComponents puede llegar a tener un tope máximo de lineas de código.

El error aparece cuando intenta cargarse la interfaz con sus objetos... ya intente con **Clean and build** al proyecto, ya intenté copiando y pasando código a una clase nueva.

¿Alguien sabe como solucionar este tema? estoy usando NetBeans 8.2

Comment: Por favor, agrega el código como texto, y no como imagen. Así será fácil de leer, copiar y modificar.

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas **Netbeans**, te comento que a mi me paso un error parecido resulta que hay un límite de objetos para el método `initComponents()`, solo que a mi me aparecia al compilar, elimine algunos objetos de Form y se soluciono.